# Dollar sign doesn`t interpolate brackets in c#

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I'm trying to create a string with the c# feature which uses the $ ( dollar sign ). The outcome would be like this **{{name}}**. The only thing I capture si the name and then I want to do something like E.G

**$"{{name}}"**

So my question is how to capture the whole thing? including brackets in a string? E.G "{{name}}"?
It seems that I cannot do that with the $ sign.

This is what I tried

```
emailHtmlBuilder.Replace($"{{paramsHtml.Name}}", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(paramsHtml.Value))};
```

The template has some placeholders E.G **{{thisIsPlaceholder}}**. And I want to replace the whole thing 
**{{thisIsPlaceholder}}** with E.G cup

Or shall I use regex in order to create that string?

Comment: `{{` is a single *literal* `{` and `}}` is a `}` in an interpolated string literal.

Comment: You probably want `$"{{{{{paramsHtml.Name}}}}}"` -- the first and second `{{` are the escape characters for a literal `{`, and the final `{` is the start of a placeholder in the interpolated string. It's probably clearer to write `"{{" + paramsHtml.Name + "}}"` at this point!

Comment: @canton7 you can post it as an answer to accept it :) Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want `$"{{{{{paramsHtml.Name}}}}}"`.

The first and second `{{` are the escape characters for a literal `{`, and the final `{` is the start of a placeholder in the interpolated string. Likewise the `}`'s.

However, it's probably clearer to write `"{{" + paramsHtml.Name + "}}"` at this point -- it compiles to the same thing, in this case.